# SiteCore-Shifting of a placeholder above and inhibiting the edit of further items in the page in Edit Mode

Tags: sitecore, placeholder

I have following arrangement of placeholders in the site.

```
top-placeholder
bottom-placeholder
```

Here top-placeholder will hold a sublayout displaying the Image and bottom-placeholder showing some navigation links in the site. Here in the edit mode, whenever I delete the sublayout shown in the top-placeholder the navigation in the bottom-placeholder moves top and after this I can't edit further and also can't insert the image again in the top-placeholder as I don't see the top-placeholder again.

Please let me know if I am missing any setting or what could be the issue for shifting of sublayout containing navigation links and not allowing me to edit/insert image again.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like after you remove the sublayout from your **top-placeholder**, it is collapsed as there is no content inside and there are no css styles that would set some minimum height and width for this placeholder. That's why you can not select it to add new sublayouts.

Try to add some additional css styles that will be displayed only in page editor editing mode ( **Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing** ) that will set the minimum height and width of the **top-placeholder**.

Comment: Hi Maras.I tried the below code                         
<% if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing){%>
<sc:Placeholder ID="toprow" runat="server" Key="top-placeholder" CssClass="topContainer"></sc:Placeholder><sc:Placeholder ID="bottomrow" runat="server" Key="bottom-placeholder"></sc:Placeholder><%}else{%><sc:Placeholder ID="toprows" runat="server" Key="top-placeholder"></sc:Placeholder><sc:Placeholder ID="bottomrows" runat="server" Key="bottom-placeholder" ></sc:Placeholder><%}%>.Here topContainer has  min-height:240px;.But still not working any idea?

Comment: Try something like this:   
  <head>
      <% if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing){%>
        <style type="text/css">
            .topContainer { min-width: 300px; min-height: 300px; background-color: Red /* just to see where the placehoder is */ }
        </style>
      <% } %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <sc:Placeholder ID="toprow" runat="server" Key="top-placeholder" CssClass="topContainer"></sc:Placeholder>
    <sc:Placeholder ID="bottomrow" runat="server" Key="bottom-placeholder"></sc:Placeholder>
  </body>